# merging two cvs files by column name

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to merge two CVS files by column but getting error.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/fantasyfinal')

a = pd.read_csv("statsmerger.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("team.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on = 'player')
merged.to_csv("output1.csv", index=False)
```

I expect the new file to fill the empty column in the first column.
i'm getting KeyError: 'player'

Comment: Make sure your two dataframes contain `player` column

Comment: [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge), if they have a common column, use `on`. Otherwise, use `left_on` and `right_on`.

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247) of both dataframes.  This isn't a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can you add a sample of both the dataset with the column name?

Answer (score 0):

One of your dataframes doesn't seem to have the `player` column.
You can check this by using `a.columns` and `b.columns` to see the columns' names.

Be aware that when you use

```
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
```

and `player` has at least one missing value, it will drop the entire column.
To avoid that, you can use

```
b = b.dropna()
```

instead, and it will drop the rows.